# Как решить ошибку Discord.py TypeError: send_message() got an unexpected keyword argument 'tts'?

Tags: python, discord

дс бот стал выдавать ошибку при отправке сообщений.
TypeError: send_message() got an unexpected keyword argument 'tts'.
Сообщения не отправляются.
фрагмент кода. Появилась ошибка внезапно. Поиск по гуглу не помог.

```
@client.event
async def on_guild_channel_create(channel):
  c = client.get_channel(log_c_id)
  await c.send(f'''создан канал {channel.name}, {channel.id}''')
введите сюда код
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

если вы используете старую версию дискорд, то ошибка может возникнуть из-за того, что аргумент `tts` больше не поддерживается. Вместо этого в новых версиях необходимо использовать `tts=True`.

```
@client.event
async def on_guild_channel_create(channel):
    c = client.get_channel(log_c_id)
    await c.send(f"Создан канал {channel.name}, {channel.id}", tts=True)
```

Comment: Большое спасибо!